# DocumentApp openById invalid argument

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am currently creating a program to open a txt file from a shared folder using the id. However, it outputted this error:

> Invalid argument (line 14, file "main") line 14

```
var file2 = DocumentApp.openById("1CdUmn9aw2q94lx4Rbj7eYl0s8DAbt8Hq");
```

I have tried DriveApp to check if my string was wrong, but it was correct. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: DocumentApp can only open Google Documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation / Issue:**

[DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE')](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String)) requires a `document` ID but you are passing a `file` ID.

**Solution:**

Instead you want to try [DriveApp.getFileById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilebyidid):

`var file2 = DriveApp.getFileById(id)`

and this will return an instance of the [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) class. Check the attached link for the available methods you can use with `file2`.